# SSH Tunneling does it multiplex?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, port-forwarding

I'm writing an application which will be doing something similar to SSH tunnelling (port forwarding and reverse port forwarding). However, SSH will not be involved at all, hence why I'm not using any existing libraries to do this.

What I'd like to know is how SSH currently achieves tunnelling. Are tunnels multiplexed over the initial SSH connection, or are multiple connections created for each tunnel?

Answer (score 0):

[OpenSSH can do multiplexing](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Multiplexing):

> OpenSSH can re-use an existing TCP connection for multiple concurrent SSH sessions rather than creating a new one each time.

Comment: Does this mean that tunnels setup on an SSH session are multiplexed though, in the default configuration? I'm aware I can change the configuration to force multiplexing.